# Lenovo A390 won't turning on and vibrates

Tags: lenovo, power-on, mediatek

My Lenovo phone doesn't turn on. When I connect it to the PC, it vibrates. The PC sees it as a MediaTek PreLoader USB VCOM Port. On flashing, the SP Flash Tool gave me a `Scatter storage type error`. How to fix it? Flash the preloader?

Before flashing, I formatted it, and the phone started flashing, but didn't turn on.

Comment: Was "Scatter storage type error" the full error message, nothing more?

Comment: Scatter storage type error: target type:hw_emmc_none

Comment: "None" could mean that the emmc storage is defect and thus can not be used anymore. Considering the age of the phone this would be a possible explanation.